# SwiftUI toolbar covered by keyboard accessory view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-form

Hi there I have a tricky problem to solve with SwiftUI in Xcode 12.4 (iOS 14): given I have a `Form` with numerous sections and `TextEditor`s, this form having a `.toolbar` modifier (bottom bar) with some content (button in this case). All of it is wrapped within `NavigationView`. Once user clicks into one of the `TextEditor`, the bottom ***toolbar gets covered by keyboard's system accessory view***. Note that I don't modify the safe areas at all. Anyone has an idea what is wrong with the code below?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var narrative: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Test 1")) {
                    Text("Bla Bla Bla")
                }
                Section(header: Text("Test 2")) {
                    Text("Bla Bla Bla")
                }
                Section(header: Text("Test 3")) {
                    Text("Bla Bla Bla")
                }
                Section(header: Text("Test 4")) {
                    Text("Bla Bla Bla")
                }
                Section(header: Text("Test 5")) {
                    Text("Bla Bla Bla")
                }
                Section(header: Text("Text Editor 1")) {
                    TextEditor(text: $narrative)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Test 6")) {
                    Text("Bla Bla Bla")
                }
                Section(header: Text("Test 7")) {
                    Text("Bla Bla Bla")
                }
                Section(header: Text("Test 8")) {
                    Text("Bla Bla Bla")
                }
                Section(header: Text("Test 9")) {
                    Text("Bla Bla Bla")
                    TextEditor(text: $narrative)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Title")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) { Button("Press me") { }  }
            })
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

[image]